# Why I didnt see the result in my extended constructor in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, constructor, middleware

I have few classes which extends from the abstract class 
And Class MenuController Extends from SiteAdminController
I need to call MenuController and receive authenticated user id

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\SiteAdmin;

use App\Http\Categories;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Gate;
use App\Category;
use App\Http\Controllers\MenuController;
use App\Site_categories;
use Auth;

class SiteAdminController extends \App\Http\SiteEntity implements Categories
{      
    protected $host;
    public $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }

    protected function menu() {
        return $data_nav['menu'] = MenuController::index('admin_categories');
    }
```

Other one extends from SiteAdminCntroller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\SiteAdmin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Gate;
use Auth;
use App\Category;


class MenuController extends SiteAdminController
{
    public $category_menu;
    public $user_categories;
    public $user;

    public function __construct(Auth $auth)
    {    
         //parent::__construct();
         $this->user_categories=$this->CategoriesMenu();
         $this->user=$auth::guard('admin')->user()->id;
         dd($this->user);
         //dd($this->user_categories);
    }
```

I think the constructor in the MenuController run befor the middlware in SiteAdminController 
Thats why I have such error
http://prntscr.com/hwfifx
Please Explaine what have I do to see result from me dd() function?
I was trying even to call `parent::__construct` but it not helping

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I use Laravel 5.4.36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that the the code in the constructor runs before the middleware: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15072

The easiest way to get around this is to use the `middleware` method in the controller:

**MenuController**

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->middleware(function () {
        $this->user_categories = $this->CategoriesMenu();
        $this->user = auth()->guard('admin')->user()->id;
    });
}
```

Comment: please help to write my middleware as you wrote with my settings `$this->middleware('auth:admin');`

Comment: You didnt set the name of middleware in your exaple How can I do it?

Comment: So I see that I can not set up class properties in constructor While I use in constructor middleware.Even I use middleware in routes but I can not set up propertie user

Comment: @David the code above is meant to be for the  constructor in the `MenuController`. You don't need to change the code in your `SiteAdminController`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if the class see another class that must be extended with.

Then try below approach (it s just example):

```
class ConceptController extends \SiteAdminController {

public function __construct(SiteAdminController $siteAdmin) {

     parent::__construct($siteAdmin);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please explaine me what is ContextInstance ? Where it have to be

Comment: Even in the SiteAdminController i have such error When I do this

Comment: `public function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    $this->user=Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id;
    dd($this->user);

    }`

Comment: 1. check if extended class is included correctly 2. put as param the object to constructor 3. use param in constructor as in example

Comment: So I see that I can not set up class properties in constructor While I use in constructor middleware.Even I use middleware in routes but I can not set up propertie user –